# Oreo FCM Notification Icon not showing when app is killed (Closed fully)

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

Android Oreo is not showing the notification icon correctly in the status bar and on the notification itself when app is closed fully(killed).It works fine when the app is open in the foreground.

```
    int notificationId = new Random().nextInt(60000);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, notificationId + 1,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        setupChannels();
    }
    String CHANNEL_ID = getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);

    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    if (imageUrl != null && !imageUrl.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        bitmap = getBitmapfromUrl(imageUrl);
    }
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(ctx, CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setContentTitle(notificationTitle)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigPictureStyle()
                            .setSummaryText(notificationMsg)
                            .bigPicture(bitmap))/*Notification with Image*/
                    .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                    .setContentText(msg)
                    .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mBuilder.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

    mBuilder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(), getNotificationIcon()));
    mBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon());

    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    mBuilder.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    private int getNotificationIcon() {
       boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O);
       return useWhiteIcon ? R.mipmap.ic_launcher_icon_round : R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
    }
```

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: So you are claiming that this works properly for all other Android versions?

Comment: Ya its working fine for all other devices including Oreo, but the issue is its not showing the notification icon when the app is closed fully in Oreo only.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: facing issue for Android 8 & 9 also. Did you found any solution? @MohammedThufail